# Why does watch not show anything on screen when invoked with timeout in an script?

Tags: bash, macos, watch

When I run this script, it **does not** display the `watch` output on the screen, and **does not** timeout after 5s.

```bsh
§ cat script.sh
#!/bin/bash
timeout 5s watch -n 1 ps
```

This is what I see on the screen when I run the script:

[image]

However, running the content of the script directly in the terminal works as expected: i.e.,

```
§ timeout 5s watch -n 1 ps
```

**What exactly is happening under the covers that is preventing `watch` from showing the content on the screen when invoked from a script?**

Furthermore, using the `--foreground` option of `timeout` in the script makes it work as expected, but I don't understand why.

If it matters, here are versions of the tools:

```
§ bash --version
bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin19)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

§ watch -v
watch from procps-ng 3.3.12-dirty

§ timeout --version
timeout (GNU coreutils) 8.29
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <https://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Padraig Brady.
```

Answer (score 1):

The behavior of `timeout` is different when it is run from a shell script. The `--foreground` option forces the default "interactive" behavior, even when run from a script. From the manpage:

```
--foreground

    when not running timeout directly from a shell prompt, allow COMMAND to
    read from the TTY and get TTY signals; in this mode, children of
    COMMAND will not be timed out
```

And `watch` needs to write to the terminal in order to do all of its fancy ANSI tricks.

If you want to see that in action, try the following:

```
$ script -c 'timeout --foreground 5s watch -n 1 ps'
$ less typescript
```

Comment: Nice one, thanks :-)

Comment: Makes sense. But are we meant to use the `--foreground` option whenever we use it in a script? Writing to output is one thing, but shouldn't it at least timeout even if we don't use that switch? I gathered as much from the documentation about this flag, but I don't get how the ability to get TTY signals is related to the fact that it does not time out.